# C++ Unexpected calculation in program

Tags: c++, function, arguments, command-line-arguments

When my program is ran with a command line argument like 60, the first calculation is wrong but the rest seem to be correct. I think I have a bug in the main() function but I cannot find it. On Linux 60 gives ~30000 steps and on Windows it shows ~-7000000 steps.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void printcollatz( int i ) {

    int count;

    int originalnumber = i;

    int workingnumber = i;

    while( workingnumber >= 1 ) {

        if( workingnumber == 1 ) {

            cout << originalnumber << " takes " << count << " steps" << endl;

            count = 0;

            break;
        }

        if( workingnumber % 2 == 0 ) {

            workingnumber /= 2;

            count++;
        }
        else {

            workingnumber = ( 3 * workingnumber ) + 1;

            count++;
        }
    }
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {

    int incrementnumber;

    if( argc > 1 ) {

        if( atoi( argv[1] ) == 0 ) {

            incrementnumber = 2;
        }
        else {

            incrementnumber = atoi( argv[1] );
        }
    }

    while( 1 ) {

        printcollatz( incrementnumber );

        incrementnumber++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You haven't initialized `count`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to initialize count:

```
int count = 0;
```

Also you might want to add a termination condition to your loop.

Comment: I'm considering when I want it to stop. When I figure it out I will add it in.